# Show that for any eigenvalue we can find a real-valued eigenfunction (for the laplacian)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open bounded set with smooth boundary. Consider $$-\bigtriangleup q(x) = \lambda q(x)$$ with either Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions $$q(x)=0, x \in \partial \Omega$$or $$\bigtriangledown q(x) \centerdot n(x) = 0, x \in \partial \Omega$$ I need to show that for any eigenvalue, we can find a real-valued eigenfunction. I have shown that the eigenvalues are real by taking the conjugate of the pde, multiplying the conjugate one by $q$ and the non-conjugate one by the conjugate of $q$ and integrating. I've tried subtracting the conjugate equation from the original and integrating but that didn't get me anywhere. The best I can get from doing any integration is that $\frac{q(x)}{\bigtriangleup q(x)}$ is real but that follows immediately from the pde if you know $\lambda$ is real. I've been stuck for a while and don't know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Multiply by $\bar{q}$, integrate over the domain. Then integrate by parts the LHS. That should do the trick.

Comment: @maxmilgram what am I supposed to get from doing that? The boundary term vanishes and the other term is a dot product of two gradients. If i integrate that term by parts I get another vanishing boundary term and the conjugate of what I started with which is the RHS if you substitute the pde back in.

Comment: You get $||\nabla q||_{L^2}^2=\lambda||q||_{L^2}^2$, don't you?

Comment: Yeah that's what I got, I guess I just don't see how that means $q$ is real.

Comment: Oh! Really sorry my bad, i missread that as "eigenvalues". So I gave a proof for eigenvalues being real. I dont think your statement about eigenfunctions is actually true. Take a real eigenfunction $q(x)$. Then $i\cdot q(x)$ is an eigenfunction as well.

Comment: No worries, that makes sense. I should've been more clear in what I'm asked to do. I'm actually asked to show that for any eigenvalue we can find a real-valued eigenfunction. I probably misinterpreted that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Tell me if this is right. If we have a complex valued eigenfunction, write is as it's real and imaginary part. Then each part is also an eigenfunction and they are both real.

Comment: This is correct for real eigenvalues since you have no "interplay" between real and imaginary part of $q$. Since all eigenvalues are real this holds for all eigenvalues.

Comment: I know my question is already answered, but can you explain what you mean by interplay and how complex eigenvalues would change this?

Comment: If you have a complex eigenvalue $\lambda=a+ib$ with eigenfunctions $q+ip$, the equation reads $\Delta q + i\Delta p = a q - b p + i (a p + b q)$. If you now look at the real and imaginary part of this equation you see that the real and imaginary part of the eigenfunction are not eigenfunctions themselves.

Comment: Thank you good sir!